# Error while adding google analytics in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on google analytics in my app,I have a library project of google play services added to project as library and defined in gradle.Now for google analytics i have added

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
.
.
.
.
.

    compile project(':google-play-services_libs')

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
.
.
.
.

}
```

And when i am building project,It is giving me error,

```
  Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

CAn anybuddy help me how to resolve this issue.please i am stuck at this issue since 4 days with no luck.

Comment: `compile project(':google-play-services_libs')` huh? did you import project from eclipse? there is no need for this when you working with gradle and aar....

Comment: @selvin -yes ,I am new to android studio and gradle so much confused..:9 need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
compile project(':google-play-services_libs')
```

and also the google play services jar file from libs folder if it is there.
You don't need to add the entire google play services.you can just add the required dependencies such as analytics, maps or gcm etc.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add by only one dependenciy here.Please

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'  in dependencies

Comment: ohk bro,i got it,so i have to add individual dependencies,for map,gcm etc...rite?

Comment: yes.you can find the list of apis here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: i am trying to add individual dependencies,During this i am getting error `Error:(30, 39) error: package com.google.android.gms.location does not exist`

Comment: package name is wrong.please look in the link provided above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107832/discussion-between-sulphuric-acid-and-ravi-teja).

Answer (score 0):

you adding the dependency twice remove one from these two. since your in android studio, remove jar from libs and and the

```
compile project(':google-play-services_libs')
```

Comment: i know that and that's my question how to solve it,not to ask again